# Doing an authenticated shallow read on Firebase Realtime Database via REST API, from within a Firebase Cloud Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Inside a firebase cloud function, I need to read a location in a Firebase RTDB.

I only want a shallow read, i.e. a list of keys, not the entire database tree below that location. I can easily do it like this via the REST API *if* that location was made generally readable without authorization.

```
https://DATABSEID.firebaseio.com/PATH/IN/DATABASE.json?shallow=true
```

However I need this location of the database not to generally permit reads. In other parts of my Firebase Cloud function index.js, I can use the Firebase Admin SDK to do all kinds of reads and writes to any location, overriding anything set in the Database Rules.

Sadly, I don't have this freedom when my cloud function calls the REST API. When it calls the REST API, it always seems to be unauthenticated. It can get globally-accessible information, but I have not figured out how to read from the location "/PATH/IN/DATABASE" that I have not made globally accessible.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://DATABSEID.firebaseio.com",
});


async function doShallowRead() {
const idToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken("Shallow-Reader");
const response = await fetch(
    "https://DATABSEID.firebaseio.com/PATH/IN/DATABASE.json?shallow=true",
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  console.log(
    "Response was ",
    JSON.stringify(response)
  );                                      // Response was {"size":0,"timeout":0}
  const shallow = await response.json();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(shallow))    // {"error":"Unauthorized request."}
...
}


exports.callMyFunction = functions.https.onCall(
  async (/*data, context */) => {
    await doShallowRead();
    console.log("OK")
  }
);
```

I tried the above but I am getting the error message above, namely "Unauthorized request"

I have also tried this to get an idToken, but the result was the same

```
const idToken = await admin.credential.applicationDefault().getAccessToken();
```

It's quite frustrating and I am going mad reading the documentation and going in circles. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the [Identity Platform REST API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api) and more precisely the [`signInWithPassword`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api#section-sign-in-email-password) endpoint.

You call it with the username and password of a user declared in the Firebase Auth service (and of course who has the desired access to your RTDB) and you'll get an ID Token in the Response Payload.

Then, when calling the RTDB REST API, you need to pass the ID Token as the auth=<ID_TOKEN> query string parameter, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token).

Comment: Makes me nervous to directly include a username/password combo, but I guess it is no more scary than having the serviceAccount.json in the cloud, wherever it is that the firebase functions are actually deployed to! I will give it a shot...

Comment: You can store them as [secret parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret_parameters)

Comment: Many thanks! Now I have a new problem which I will ask separately!

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with your service account which is key to authenticating.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as serviceAccountObject from './serviceAccount.json';

const serviceAccount = serviceAccountObject as admin.ServiceAccount;
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I accindentally removed that line during my simplification of this for presentation here - I will add it back in.